# Images in a CustomTableCell gets resized upon click

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6.1, sdwebimage

This would be impossible to explain without a project, hence I uploaded a small [**DEMO**](https://github.com/houmie/testTable) on GitHub.

I don't think the constraints are wrong. The image should be fixed in its place. Initially `SDWebImage` retrieves the image from the cache, but once I click on the image, the image gets resized. (It gets smaller, see top image)

[image]

Funny enough in my demo the images show first as red squares.  Once you click on them the imageView resizes and the actual image loads. This still shows the problem though.

[image]

It seems to me the initial cache is not resizing according to the constraints. Could that be true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this fixes it:

```
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL
                      placeholderImage: nil
                             completed:^(UIImage image, NSError error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                                 [cell setNeedsLayout];
                             }];
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your Code

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
BookmarkTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:bookmarkcellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

News *news = [_news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.headLine.text = news.headLine;

[cell.newsImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",news.imageUrlList]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iTagImageHolder"]];
 [cell.newsImage.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];
[cell.newsImage.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];


return cell;
}
```

I got the output like

[image]

in storyboard I select the `Autoresize subviews` in `attributes inspectors

[image]

Comment: else check you were changed the image frame in any where

Comment: sorry, it doesnt work. Feel free to clone my github demo and give it a shot. Thanks

Comment: @Houman -- check the updated answer , in here i checked to select the image and scroll the table it showing perfectly , any issues

Comment: sorry for late comment. Unfortunately it doesnt work. If you look at the red image holder, it is still a different size. Once you click on the image and it loads, it is then a different size again.  How can we stop the `ImageView` from being resized?